# How can I pull a list of users from a shell log file?

Tags: linux, sh

An entry in the log file I have been given looks like this.

```
174.71.76.52 - - [01/Dec/2016:17:22:34 -0600] "GET /~csymons/project/css/normalize.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

My problem is pulling a unique list of users (one of which, in this case, ~csymons) from the file.

I've been using this command to get the list of users, those of which are found just after "GET". However, if the request comes back as just a "/" after, then it will not be logged as a user.

I've been using this command so far, but am having trouble molding it to fit the criteria.

```
 cat logfile | awk '{print $6,$7}' | uniq | sort
```

Output chunk of this would be

```
"GET /~ejoyce/a3/images/123.jpg
"GET /
"GET /1300-1-xhtml/610.html
"GET /1300-1-xhtml/608.html
"GET /1300-4-cgi/10-3.cgi
"GET /1300-1-xhtml/606.html
"GET /1300-4-cgi/09-3.cgi
"GET /
"GET /1300-1-xhtml/612.html
"GET /2850-1-vanilla/08b.cgi
"GET /2850-1-vanilla/11b.cgi
"GET /2850-1-vanilla/12b.cgi
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /1300-2-css/219.html
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /1300-2-css/213.html
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /1300-3-forms/
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /2850-3-templates/
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /1300-1-xhtml/415.html
"GET /
"GET /~ejoyce/a3/images/123.jpg
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /~ejoyce/a3/images/123.jpg
"GET /
"GET /robots.txt
"GET /
"GET /2850-3-templates/
"GET /
```

I'm specifically trying to find the users. Such as GET /~ejoyce/a3/images/123.jpg --> ejoyce

When using cat logfile | awk '{print $7}' | sed 's#^[^~]*/([^/][^/]*)/.*$#\1#'  | uniq -d | sort

```
images
images
images
images
~jpcollins
~jpcollins
~jpcollins
~lkcantu
~lkcantu
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
~robert
/robots.txt
/robots.txt
/robots.txt
/robots.txt
/robots.txt
```

*There is more, logfile has over 900 entries*

Appreciate any tips to help solve this!

Comment: Do all users have `~` beginning the name? If so, `sed 's#^[^~]*/\([^/][^/]*\)/.*$#\1#'` will work. Or if you have extended regular expressions available to `sed`, then `sed -E 's#^[^~]+([^/]+)/.*$#\1#'` would be preferable. You can adjust where `'~'` appears to either include/exclude from the name.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please add to your question a sample log with good lines, and with "bad" lines.  Show us what you are getting right now, and what you would rather see as result.  See [ask] and provide a [mcve].  This log file looks like an Apache httpd log, and not all requests are necessarily going to be to user directories.

Comment: Here's an example of a log that would be ignored                                           
 41.141.165.6 - - [01/Dec/2013:18:40:11 -0600] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6819

Comment: `sed -n -E 's#^[^~]+~([^/]+)/.*$#\1#p'`

Answer (score 0):

If all your usernames are in lowercase this should work:
`sed -n 's/.*GET\s\/~\?\([a-z]\+\).*/\1/p' logfile`
Additionally swap the `[a-z]` for a `[a-zA-Z]` if usernames do include capital letters.
Also if the `~` is persistent across all users feel free to remove `\?` following it.

Comment: I ran it alongside this script with and without \? and it's not returning anything for some reason. Looking to see if there's a way to go ahead and tweak that now

Comment: Strange, maybe it is an issue with certain characters needing to be escaped in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

With your additional input and clarification of whether you wanted `~ejoyce` or `ejoyce`, you can use:

```
sed -n -E 's#^[^~]+~([^/]+)/.*$#\1#p' logfile | sort -u
```

On the file above, that would result in a single output

```
ejoyce
```

Comment: ejoyce
ejoyce HTTP
jpcollins
lkcantu
robert                                                                                                                                            Anyway I can add to this to remove the HTTP from the second ejoyce?

Comment: This looks for the first `'~'` and then takes what comes after up to the next `'/'` as the name.